# Java Constructor call

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

Is there any other way to call constructor, other than new object creation from new operator?

I think when constructor chaining happens in inheritance then also constructor gets called but it does not create parent class object.

Comment: Actually -- what specifically are you asking here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, one way is to have your contructor call some method:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public SomeClass() {
        init();
    }

    public final void init() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then call `init()` again later when needed